# Django translation and model inheritance

Tags: django

Django 1.11

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'general',
    'general_frame',
...
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True
```

**general/models.py**

```
class GeneralModel(models.Model):
    """Sharing common features of models."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                             null=False,
                             blank=False,
                             default="",
                             verbose_name=_("title"))
```

**general_frame/models.py**

```
class GeneralFrame(GeneralModel):

    DOCUMENT = 'D'
    PHOTO = 'P'
    PHOTO_DOCUMENT_CHOICES = ((None, '----'),
                              (DOCUMENT, _('document')),
                              (PHOTO, _('photo')),)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PHOTO_DOCUMENT_CHOICES,
                            blank=False,
                            null=False,
                            default="---",
                            verbose_name=_('type'))
```

I have executed makemessages and compilemessages. The structure is as follows:

**Project structure:**

```
├── general
│   ├── locale
│   │   └── ru_RU
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           ├── django.mo
│   │           └── django.po
├── general_frame
│   ├── locale
│   │   └── ru_RU
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           ├── django.mo
│   │           └── django.po
```

The problem is: everything in GeneralFrame is translated, bot GeneralModel is not translated. I mean that document, photo and type are translated. But title is not translated.

I made messages, checked .po files and recompiled messages again several times.

Could you give me a kick here?

Comment: What is `_` there? Can you please add the import lines to your code?

Comment: Gökhan Sarı, thank you very much for the kick. In "general" it was ugettext_lazy. If you organize an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Just two words "Check import".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my wild guess was true eh? :)

For django to discover your translated string, you need to make sure you wrap the string with one of django's translation methods, you can find about it on [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation). Make sure you imported required translation method like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# now you can use _('your string'), and django will discover your string
```